# Extract date from a string in java

Tags: java, string, date, string-matching

I have a string as following :

```
String str = "skip=anthing&id='234234432234' and (timestamp le 2017-01-17T05:05:55:358Z and timestamp ge 2017-01-17T08:05:55:358Z)&format=json";
```

I want to extract the date part from the string put it inside single quotes and replace it back to original string.

The resultant string should be

```
String str = "skip=anything&id='234234432234' and (timestamp le '2017-01-17T05:05:55:358Z' and timestamp ge '2017-01-17T08:05:55:358Z')&format=json"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use the following regex

```
String input = "skip=anthing&id='234234432234' and (timestamp le 2017-01-17T05:05:55:358Z and timestamp ge 2017-01-17T08:05:55:358Z)&format=json";
String output = input.replaceAll("(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{3}Z)", "'$1'");
System.out.println(output); // skip=anthing&id='234234432234' and (timestamp le '2017-01-17T05:05:55:358Z' and timestamp ge '2017-01-17T08:05:55:358Z')&format=json
```

Comment: or if you do not like the  '[0-9]' format just use '\d' for any number. So the java regex will be : "(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{3}Z)"

Comment: @Novy Yes, you are right. I've mistakenly thought that \d{n} will not match numbers started with zero, e.g. 01. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Novy for the help.

Comment: I've realized I accidentally downvoted your answer when looking at it (realized this just now, 5 days later). Could you edit it (don't need to change anything) so I may undo it?

Comment: @Mar Dev try to vote it positive, it may undo our down vote.